# Making Spring Batch ItemReader restartable

Tags: spring-batch

The spring Batch program which I am working on is reading data from a table. It’s using ‘org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader’ itemReader . Earlier the plan was to Alter table and add a PROCESSED_INDICATOR flag and prepopulate it with status ‘PENDING’. Once the record is processed and writer will update the status of PROCESSED_INDICATOR flag to ‘Processed’. This is to support re-startability . For example if batch picks up 1 million records and died in ½ million records then when I restart the batch; it should start where I have left off.
But unfortunately, management didn’t approve this solution. I am digging in ways to make itemreader re-startable. As per Spring documentation “Most ItemReaders have much more sophisticated restart logic. The JdbcCursorItemReader, for example, stores the row id of the last processed row in the Cursor.”

Does anyone have any sample example of such custom reader which implements JdbcCursorItemReader and stores last processed row in the cursor.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

==FULL XML CONFIGURATION==

```
<import resource="classpath:/batch/utility/skip/batch_skip.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/batch/config/context-postgres.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/batch/config/oracle-database.xml" />

<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:/batch/jobs/TPF-1001-DD-01/TPF-1001-DD-01.properties" />
<bean id="gridSizePartitioner"
    class="com.tpf.partitioner.GridSizePartitioner" />

      <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="${pool.size}" />
<batch:job id="XYZJob" job-repository="jobRepository"
    restartable="true">

    <batch:step id="XYZSTEP">
        <batch:description>Convert TIF files to PDF</batch:description>
        <batch:partition partitioner="gridSizePartitioner">

            <batch:handler task-executor="taskExecutor"
                grid-size="${pool.size}" />
            <batch:step>
                <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                    <batch:chunk commit-interval="${commit.interval}"
                        skip-limit="${job.skip.limit}">

                        <batch:reader>
                            <bean id="timeReader"
                                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
                                scope="step">
                                <property name="dataSource" ref="oracledataSource" />
                                <property name="sql">
                                    <value>                                     
                                    select TIME_ID as timesheetId,count(*),max(CREATION_DATETIME) as creationDateTime , ILN_NUMBER as ilnNumber
                                    from TS_FAKE_NAME
                                    where creation_datetime  >= '#{jobParameters['creation_start_date1']} 12.00.00.000000000 AM' 
                                    and creation_datetime &lt;  '#{jobParameters['creation_start_date2']} 11.59.59.999999999 PM' 
                                    and mod(time_id,${pool.size})=#{stepExecutionContext['partition.id']} 
                                    group by  time_id ,ILN_NUMBER                                   

                                    </value>
                                </property>
                                <property name="rowMapper">
                                    <bean
                                        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper">
                                        <property name="mappedClass"
                                            value="com.tpf.model.Time" />
                                    </bean>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </batch:reader>
                        <batch:processor>
                            <bean id="compositeItemProcessor"
                                class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
                                <property name="delegates">
                                    <list>
                                        <ref bean="timeProcessor" />
                                    </list>
                                </property>

                            </bean>
                        </batch:processor>


                        <batch:writer>
                            <bean id="compositeItemWriter"
                                class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
                                <property name="delegates">
                                    <list>
                                        <ref bean="timeWriter" />
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </batch:writer>
                        <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                            <batch:include
                                class="com.utility.skip.BatchSkipException" />
                        </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:listeners>
                            <batch:listener ref="batchSkipListener" />
                        </batch:listeners>
                    </batch:chunk>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:validator>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.DefaultJobParametersValidator">
            <property name="requiredKeys">
                <list>
                    <value>batchRunNumber</value>
                    <value>creation_start_date1</value>
                    <value>creation_start_date2</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </batch:validator>
</batch:job>



<bean id="timesheetWriter" class="com.tpf.writer.TimeWriter"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="timeProcessor"
    class="com.tpf.processor.TimeProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracledataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any sample example of such custom reader which implements JdbcCursorItemReader and stores last processed row in the cursor

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` does that, see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html), here is an excerpt:

```
ExecutionContext: The current row is returned as restart data,
and when restored from that same data, the cursor is opened and the current row
set to the value within the restart data.
```

So you don't need a custom reader.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud .
That being said; I tested my batch.
I deleted all records from batch meta data tables.
I ran my batch job with 3 parameters batchRunNumber, creation_start_date1, creation_start_date2 as below.
 '08DEC15TO13DEC15', 08-DEC-15,13-DEC-15 
Then I made sure my batch fails; basically I disconnected from network. 
This lead my batch's exit_code as 'UNKNOWN'. I used an update sql and updated the status to be 'FAILED'.Now, here are the batch meta data tables look like.
====UPDATE STATEMENT====
update BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION 
set status = 'FAILED'
where job_execution_id = 217

Comment: ====SELECT STATEMENTS====
select * from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where  job_instance_id = 199
217 1 199 2019-01-17 11:22:04.159 2019-01-17 11:22:04.63 <null> FAILED UNKNOWN 
select * from batch_job_execution_params where job_execution_id = 217
217 STRING batchRunNumber '08DEC15TO13DEC15' 1969-12-31 16:00:00.0 0 0.0
217 STRING creation_start_date1 08-DEC-15 1969-12-31 16:00:00.0 0 0.0
217 STRING creation_start_date2 13-DEC-15 1969-12-31 16:00:00.0 0 0.0

Comment: But if I run the batch with same job parameters ..It throws below exception
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobExecution: id=217, version=1, startTime=2019-01-17 11:22:04.63, endTime=null, lastUpdated=2019-01-17 11:22:04.631, status=FAILED, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=199, version=0, Job=[TPF-1001-DD-01]], jobParameters=[{creation_start_date2=13-DEC-15, creation_start_date1=08-DEC-15, batchRunNumber='08DEC15TO13DEC15'}]
 at

Comment: Isn't the restart-ability means ; if batch fails for given set of job parameters ..and we try to run again..with same set of parameters.. Batch should start and pick up from it is left off.

Comment: If you still have a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`, this means there is a **step** execution with status `STARTING` or `STARTED` or `STOPPING`. So you need to make sure to update the status of step executions associated to the job execution 217 to `FAILED` as well. The relevant code section is the following: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.java#L100-L122

Comment: I updated status of step executions associated to job execution 217 to FAILED in batch_step_execution table using below sql====update batch_step_execution set status = 'FAILED' where job_execution_id = 217====But when I run the job with same parameter it's the same exception thrown but at different plac

Comment: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=199, version=0, Job=[TPF-1001-DD-01]
 at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:120)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine Can I provide you any other detail. Really want to understand what's stopping my batch to be restart able.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example on github with an embedded database and I try to help you.